# Why does the werewolf exhale a green mist?

Tags: plot-explanation, being-human

I have only watched a few episodes of Being Human (the original BBC series) so I may have missed something. (Just got hold of the dvds so trying to catch up.)  In episode 3, George transforms into a werewolf after/during fighting Tully in the shed.  He exhales a green mist just after the transformation has finished.  I didn't notice this in any other episode, did it have something to do with fighting Tully?  Eg, proximity of another werewolf?

Any other explanation - maybe just werewolves have very bad breath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't miss anything; you just caught something that probably doesn't matter. This never shows up or comes up in any subsequent episodes. I assume it's supposed to be simply George's breath/vapor from exhaling - just not done very well! It's so short that it might also just be a reflection mistake when filming.

Incidentally, unless there's a "pilot" episode on the DVDs that I'm not aware of, this scene actually occurs in episode 2.

Comment: Thank you for this. After watching other episodes, I agree with you, it doesn't matter. Possibly his breath catching a green light. And yes, there is a pilot episode: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1349938/episodes?season=1